# Merge and add two lists of dictionaries using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of dictionaries and a piece of code that tries to merge them:

```
Json_Final =[]
try:            
    for keyIN in JSON1:
        json_data_Merge= {}
        for keyUS in JSON2:                
            if(keyIN['YEAR'] == keyUS['YEAR']) & (keyIN['MONTH'] == keyUS['MONTH'])& (keyIN['Name'] == keyUS['Name']):
                json_data_Merge['YEAR'] = keyIN['YEAR']
                json_data_Merge['MONTH'] = keyIN['MONTH']
                json_data_Merge['Name'] = keyIN['Name']
                json_data_Merge['Total']= int(keyIN['Total']) + int(keyUS['Total'])
        Json_Final.append(json_data_Merge)
    print( Json_Final )
except Exception as e:
    print('MergeException',e)

JSON 1 = [{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 100}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Grape", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 300}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Grape", "Total":  100}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Apple", "Total":  200}]

JSON 2 = [{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 300}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Grape", "Total": 400}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 300}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Mango", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Grape", "Total":  500}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Apple", "Total":  250}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 300}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 300}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Grape", "Total": 600},
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 300}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 300}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Mango", "Total": 200}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Grape", "Total":  600}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 200}, 
 {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Apple", "Total":  450}]
```

My Code Output:

```
[{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 300}, 
{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Grape", "Total": 600}, 
{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Grape", "Total":  300}, 
{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Apple", "Total":  450}]
```

Comment: What's the *problem* with the code you've posted? Aside from the fact that it's clearly not syntactically valid.

Comment: @jonrsharpe based on Month and Name I need to add the Totals of those two JSON's. If the name is not available, then you just add to the output.

Comment: Right, but SO isn't here to provide an implementation to meet your requirements, so what's the problem with **your code**?

Comment: Tell us what does your code actually prints.

Comment: my code only adds the Total if it exists in Two JSON list.

Comment: But I want to update the one which is available only one JSON as well

Comment: It's good to add actual output, to get better understanding.

Comment: Map the list of dictionaries to a pandas dataframe, concat them, groupby Year/Month/Name and sum the total.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I edited with my output

Comment: @KenSyme I am new to python. can you help me with grouping

Comment: Finally, you were right reposting, the other one may have stayed hold for a long time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
JSON_1 = [{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 100}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Grape", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 300}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Grape", "Total":  100}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Apple", "Total":  200}]

JSON_2 = [{"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Apple", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 1, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 300}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Grape", "Total": 400}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 300}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 2, "Name": "Mango", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Grape", "Total":  500}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Orange", "Total": 200}, 
          {"YEAR": 2019, "MONTH": 3, "Name": "Apple", "Total":  250}]

JSON_2 = {"{}_{}_{}".format(i["YEAR"], i["MONTH"], i["Name"]): i for i in JSON_2}    #Create a dict for easy loopup

for i in JSON_1:
    key = "{}_{}_{}".format(i["YEAR"], i["MONTH"], i["Name"])   #Create key with Year, Month, Name
    if key in JSON_2:                         #Check if item from JSON_1 exist in JSON_2
        JSON_2[key]['Total'] += i["Total"]    #Update Total
    else:
        JSON_2[key] = i                       #Else add new entry. 

print(list(JSON_2.values()))    #Get values.
```

**Output:**

```
[{'MONTH': 1, 'Name': 'Orange', 'Total': 300, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 2, 'Name': 'Mango', 'Total': 200, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 3, 'Name': 'Apple', 'Total': 450, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 1, 'Name': 'Apple', 'Total': 300, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 3, 'Name': 'Grape', 'Total': 600, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 3, 'Name': 'Orange', 'Total': 200, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 2, 'Name': 'Grape', 'Total': 600, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 2, 'Name': 'Apple', 'Total': 300, 'YEAR': 2019},
 {'MONTH': 2, 'Name': 'Orange', 'Total': 300, 'YEAR': 2019}]
```